# Javascript IDE-in-a Box for learning Javascript without spending all day configuring the environment?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to learn Javascript (and maybe PHP eventually). I've done desktop programming for 20 years.  What symies me is configuring the environment (editor, server, debuging, browser pluggins, etc.)

I'm happy to pay for something that makes this all "just work".

I've got XAMPP installed with phpStorm 6. (I'm checcking out phpStorm 8 in case it does a better job with all of this. ).

I'd like to have Syntax Highlighting, Auto-complete, and step-by-step debugging (integrated into the browser)

Any hopes?

Comment: check out brackets, or just use a bin/fiddle/pen

Comment: phpstorm is an awesome IDE but there are also other alternatives, as for creating a local environment Xampp will work (you can also install just services for php apache & mysql)

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple options:

- [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) for trying out your JS code in an online environment and sharing it with others for debugging purposes.
- On desktop, any JetBrains IDE would do once you enable syntax completion for JS and PHP. I've been using Webstorm for a while now, and it's pretty good. Also, I was surprised by how well JS syntax completion worked in PyCharm. So, you can't go wrong with any JetBrains IDE.
- Check out [Brackets](http://brackets.io/). It's an editor that has some interesting design support.
- Use chrome dev tools for JS stuff. As most JS is client side (exception: Node, etc.), this helps a lot in debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Excluding the server-side part, all the JS stuff happens in a browser environment. So, a modern browser combined with its Dev Tools, which offer both a debugger and a console (which is very useful!), combined with your favorite IDE (most of them support JS code highlighting, auto completion and all the fancy stuff because JS became one of THE languages)... that's how most of us do it. And it works pretty much out-of-the-box.

There are a few all-in-one solutions, but I'm not a fan of them, so I'll leave the up to other answers here. There are also a few good online sandboxes, such as codepen, jsfiddle, jsbin...

The setup is a bit harder if you want to dive into the server-side JS using Node, but I don't think that's in the question scope.

---

Btw. you might want to rephrase your question in order not to make this a "what's your favorite IDE" thread.

Answer (score 0):

Try sublime text 3, you can install packages for auto complete and syntax highlighting

http://www.sublimetext.com/3

Or Atom, which is similar with packages to do anything you want. You can run JS right in the browser.

https://atom.io/

You can also use jsfiddle and plunkr etc if you just want to work directly in the browser

Answer (score 0):

PhpStorm will be great for JS/PHP. I'm not sure what changed since version 6, but if you can get it, 8 would be better for sure. It has great built-in completion support and requires next to zero configuration. *Although I love recommended text editors (Brackets, Sublime, Atom), they require lots of configuration to get features you're looking for.*

Chrome can do JS debugging without any plugins.

To try JavaScript, you can just open the html file where you're importing it, and with XAMPP set up, you also have all of environment you need for PHP.

Answer (score -1):

I have been using brackets.io and love it.  Very simple.  If you want to do client side JS and Node then WebStorm is the way to go.

Comment: codepen is also an awesome tool for html, css and javascript prototyping.